# How to append to csv file without creating multiple copies of headers into rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv

I am trying to write **Dataframe** to **csv** :

```
for i in range 10:
    consolidated_df.to_csv(output_file_path + '/' +   dest_csv,mode='a',index=False)
```

This is creating adding headers as new rows for every iteration

```
col1 col2 col3
a     b     c
col1 col2  col3
d    e      f
col  col2   col3
g    h      i
```

if i use **header=none** in **df.to_csv** , then the **csv** doesnt have any headers at all

all i need is this

```
col1 col2 col3
a     b     c
d    e      f
g    h      i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to check if index is 0 then add header else set header to None

**Ex:**

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 0:
        consolidated_df.to_csv(output_file_path + '/' +  dest_csv,mode='a',index=False)
    else:
        consolidated_df.to_csv(output_file_path + '/' +  dest_csv,mode='a',index=False, header=None)
```